# Is the pressure at the outer hole on a pitot static tube equal to atmospheric pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, classical-mechanics

I'm looking at a pitot static tube question right now and I just need some clarification. There is the outer hole on the pitot static tube, not the hole that the air stream goes through, but the other tiny one near that. Is the pressure at that hole equal to atmospheric pressure?

Comment: What on earth is a pilot static tube?!

Comment: Look it up on google

Comment: It is your question, it is not for me to go researching in order to help you. Make sure to defined the components of your question in explicit detail. Also, accept answers if you deem them to be correct...

Comment: It's a pitot static tube. Anybody who has been introduced to fluid mechanics knows what a pitot static tube is.

Comment: The fact that I don't, means your last arrogant comment is not correct.

Comment: Well you're the one telling me to define the components of my question in detail. I shouldn't have to explain what a pitot static tube is when it's a commonly used device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Pitot tube works my measuring the difference between static and total pressure. One opening of the tube is facing the flow: this one sees the total (stagnation) pressure. The other opening is perpendicular to the flow and sees only the static pressure.

Comment: and static pressure is just the pressure of the free jetstream right?

Comment: That's correct.